# SQL Server : order by first non-empty left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a `car` table. And a `car` have  relation to the *service* with *priority* where it can be repaired.

And I have the hierarchy of the services where this `car` can be served.

1. It can be the service which is related directly to the car
2. It can be the service which is located in the city of the car
3. It can be the service which is located in the country of the car
4. It can be the default service.

And I need to order cars by the names of this services considering the hierarchy.

For example I have `car` table like:

```
ID  Name
-----------
1   Toyota
2   Tesla
3   Ford
```

`direct_service` table:

```
CAR_ID  NAME       PRIORITY
---------------------------
1       B_SERVICE  0
1       C_SERVICE  1
```

`location_service` table (location priority means that city(0) is more important than country(1)):

```
CAR_ID  NAME                  LOCATION_PRIORITY  PRIORITY
---------------------------------------------------------
1       TOYOATA_CITY_SERVICE  0                  0
2       B_SERVICE             0                  0
2       TESLA_CITY_SERVICE    0                  1
2       A_SERVICE             1                  0
```

`default_service` table:

```
CAR_ID  NAME       PRIORITY
---------------------------
3       A_SERVICE  0
3       B_SERVICE  1
```

I want to write and SQL-script which will select all cars order by its services.
Due to presented example of table values I wan to see the next result after script execution:

```
ID  Name
-----------
3   Ford
1   Toyota
2   Tesla
```

I want to have such order 'cause:

- Ford has the next service array: A_SERVICE, B_SERVICE (from `default_service`, and Ford has no any direct or location service)
- Toyota has the next service array: B_SERVICE, C_SERVICE (from `direct_service` and other services is not taken into account due to service hierarchy)
- Tesla has the next service array: B_SERVICE, TESLA_CITY_SERVICE (from `location_service`, country services is not taken into account 'cause city is more important)

Please help me to build the SQL script for this order task

Comment: I just don't follow the logic.   You introduce a specific ordering on the services.  Then you have multiple priority columns in multiple tables.   I'm lost on which applies to what when.

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?